# How to display error messages using WP_Error class?

Tags: functions, pages, errors, user-registration, wp-error

I have registration form code in my `functions.php` file like this

```
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'registration') {
       $error = new WP_Error();
        if (empty(esc_attr($_POST['email'])))
        {
            $error->add('regerror','Email is required.');
        }
        if (!is_email(esc_attr($_POST['email'])))
        {
            $error->add('regerror','Invalid email format.');

        }
        if (email_exists(esc_attr($_POST['email'])))
        {
            $error->add('regerror','Email already in use. Did you forget your Password? If yes click here to reset.');

        }
}
```

Now can someone tell me how to display those error messages in my `register page`?

### Update:

My registration page has code like this

```
<form method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<!-- form fields goes here -->
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="registration" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: That's it? Surely there is more code? This must be in a function right? Is it hooked to anything? Called directly? What?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Please check my update. Its not a function. My if loop checks the action parameter. If `action == registration` then the code will be executed. Its not hooked to anything. And yes I have some extra codes too in my if loop. I just trimmed it to make the question simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that in `functions.php` you'd probably have to declare `$error` to be `global` like so :

```
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'registration') {
    global $error;
    $error = new WP_Error();
    // the rest of your code
```

And then do `global $error;` again on your registration page before trying to use it.

But I don't understand why you have that code in `functions.php`. That seems like bad design to me. You are running that `if` conditional every time any page loads and it sounds like you only need it on your registration page, *which I am assuming is something you've written yourself and that you are not talking about the built in registration/login page at `wp-login.php`.* Given that assumption, just move that code to the registration page and it will be available with no hassle. [`WP_Error` has methods will let you get at the data.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error#Methods)

Comment: Thankyou. I'll move the code to my register page as you advised..